Traefik with FTPS , TLS offloading issue
i m trying to migrate from HAProxy to Traefik, i have an existing config of Haproxy that act as TCP loadbalancer for an FTPS server. now, i m trying to do that same with traefik.
The FPTS server Operate on the following port: 1413 for control and 1414-1420 to transfer Data. my config is the following:
gerenal View
workflow
Docker-compose.yml file
services:
traefik:
image: traefik:2.10
container_name: traefik
network_mode: host
restart: always
env_file:
  - ./traefik.env
volumes:
  - /srv/traefik/:/etc/traefik
  - /srv/traefik/logs:/logs
  - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt:ro
command: [ ]

traefik.yml Static config
api:
  insecure: true
  dashboard: true

log:
  level: "DEBUG"
  filePath: "/logs/traefik.log"

certificatesResolvers:
  letsEncrypt:
     acme:
       email: "letencr@cl.ss"  
       storage: "/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"    
       tlsChallenge: {}


entryPoints:
  ftps:
    address: ":1413"  
  ftps_data_1:
    address: ":1414"
  ftps_data_2:
    address: ":1415"
  ftps_data_3:
    address: ":1416"
  ftps_data_4:
    address: ":1417"
  ftps_data_5:
    address: ":1418"
  ftps_data_6:
    address: ":1419"
  ftps_data_7:
    address: ":1420"

metrics:
  prometheus: {}

providers:
  file:
    directory: "/etc/traefik/config"
    watch: true

serversTransport:
   insecureSkipVerify: true

tls.yml
tls:
  certificates:
    - certFile: /etc/letsencrypt/certs_project/fullchain.pem
      keyFile: /etc/letsencrypt/certs_project/key.pem

ftps_dynamic_config.yml
tcp:
  routers:
    ## Connect
    hi_ftps_connect:*
      rule: "HostSNI(`*`)"
      entryPoints:
        - "ftps"
      service: "ssl_hi_ftps_connect"
      tls: {}

    ## Data transfer
    hi_ftps_passive_1:
      rule: "HostSNI(`*`)"
      entryPoints:
        - "ftps_data_1"
      service: "ssl_hi_ftps_passive_1"
      tls: {}

    ## Data transfer
    hi_ftps_passive_2:
      rule: "HostSNI(`*`)"
      entryPoints:
        - "ftps_data_2"
      service: "ssl_hi_ftps_passive_2"
      tls: {}

    ## Data transfer
    hi_ftps_passive_3:
      rule: "HostSNI(`*`)"
      entryPoints:
        - "ftps_data_3"
      service: "ssl_hi_ftps_passive_3"
      tls: {}

    ## Data transfer
    hi_ftps_passive_4:
      rule: "HostSNI(`*`)"
      entryPoints:
        - "ftps_data_4"
      service: "ssl_hi_ftps_passive_4"
      tls: {}

    ## Data transfer
    hi_ftps_passive_5:
      rule: "HostSNI(`*`)"
      entryPoints:
        - "ftps_data_5"
      service: "ssl_hi_ftps_passive_5"
      tls: {}

    ## Data transfer
    hi_ftps_passive_6:
      rule: "HostSNI(`*`)"
      entryPoints:
        - "ftps_data_6"
      service: "ssl_hi_ftps_passive_6"
      tls: {}

    ## Data transfer
    hi_ftps_passive_7:
      rule: "HostSNI(`*`)"
      entryPoints:
        - "ftps_data_7"
      service: "ssl_hi_ftps_passive_7"
      tls: {} 

  services:
    
    ## Connect
    ssl_hi_ftps_connect:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - address: "172.20.49.6:1413" # Connectivity 
        
    ## Data transfer
    ssl_hi_ftps_passive_1:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - address: "172.20.49.6:1414" # Data 

    ## Data transfer
    ssl_hi_ftps_passive_2:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - address: "172.20.49.6:1415" # Data 

    ## Data transfer
    ssl_hi_ftps_passive_3:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - address: "172.20.49.6:1416" # Data 

    ## Data transfer
    ssl_hi_ftps_passive_4:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - address: "172.20.49.6:1417" # Data 

    ## Data transfer
    ssl_hi_ftps_passive_5:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - address: "172.20.49.6:1418" # Data 

    ## Data transfer
    ssl_hi_ftps_passive_6:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - address: "172.20.49.6:1419" # Data 

    ## Data transfer
    ssl_hi_ftps_passive_7:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - address: "172.20.49.6:1420" # Data

Treafik logs:
time="#" level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from [MY-IP]:45552: tls: client requested unsupported application protocols ([ftp])"
time="#" level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from [MY-IP]:45564: tls: client requested unsupported application protocols ([ftp])"

NOTE: i m connecting with the Filezilla Client
i don't get it, i never setup such a thing with traefik .Also, when the setup was done with haproxy , it prompt me in filezilla to accept the certifcate when i try to connect to the ftps server.
anyone that have tried to do such a config kindly provide me with some guidance?
